# Simplest Live Demonstration of Adiabatic Transport

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, condensed-matter, adiabatic, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I have to give a presentation on Berry phase. I would like to give the simplest live demonstration of adiabatic transport. If I move an object in a loop and return that object back into its original position then the phase changes. I was thinking about a moving a simple spinning wheel, but I have trouble matching two wheels to rotate in the same frequency and phase to compare them after one experiences adiabatic transport. Both wheels did not have the same friction coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for a reliable demonstration of the spinning wheel system,  a design using bearings would be essential, in order to achieve frictionless reactions.

A demonstration can be achieved by means of the linear [planimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter) , which measures areas enclosed by plane curves, by measuring a rotation angle of its wheel.

I think that a planimeter model can be built by elementary means. Please see, the following [elementary description](http://www.icmc.usp.br/pessoas/szani/sma332/material/PlanimetersCalculusRevised.pdf) by: Tanya Leise.
The planimeter returns to its original state after its tracer end completes a full turn around the closed curve, only its wheel acquires a net rotation which is a Berry phase proportional to the traced area.

In fact an elementary application of Stokes theorem shows that the area of closed planar curve $\mathcal{C}$ can be written as a Holonomy of an artificial gauge field:

$$ Area = \int_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{1}{2}(x dy - y dx) =  \int_{\mathcal{C}} \mathbf{A} \cdot  d \mathbf{r}  = \int_{\mathcal{C}}  \mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{n_z} dS$$ Where, the artificial gauge field:
$$ \mathbf{A }= \frac{1}{2}\{-y , x, 0\}$$
It's corresponding "magnetic field"
$$ \mathbf{B }=  \mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{A}  =  \{0 , 0, 1\}$$
Thus
$$ Area = \int_{\mathcal{C}}  B dS =  \int_{\mathcal{C}} dS $$